# Object Passing itself in java

Tags: java, object, behavior

I figured out how to have an object pass itself to another and have a field in it updated.
I did so by having ObjectA pass itself to ObjectB. Then ObjectB changes a field in ObjectA.
Starting in Main Method: (and leaving out method headers and such)

```
ObjA.changeField(Obj2)
```

In ObjectA

```
Obj2.callChangeMethod(this);
```

In ObjectB

```
Obj1.makeChange();
```

What I'm confused about is why did I have to pass "this" in line2 versus passing ObjA?

Thanks

Comment: can you be more explicit and give us how your variables are declared?

Comment: also, how the methods are declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is quite simple actually: it all has to do with the *scope* of the variables.

Here is a slightly embellished version of the code you presented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectA Obj1 = new ObjectA();
    ObjectB Obj2 = new ObjectB();

    Obj1.changeField(Obj2);
}
```

The thing to notice about this code is that `Obj1` and `Obj2` are declared inside of the `main` method. This means that they belong to the main method, and cannot be used outside of `main`. This is what the "scope" means. If a variable is declared inside a class, only that class has access to it. If declared in a method, only that method can use it. The same holds for loop structures, and any other kind of block you can imagine. Essentially, if the variable was declared inside a pair of `{}`, then it belongs to that pair of `{}`.

So now if you look at your `ObjectA` class, you'll notice that it sits all by itself - it *wasn't* declared as part of the `main` method, so it can't use the variable `Obj1` - the `ObjectA` code has no idea that `Obj1` even exists.

That is why you must use the `this` keyword. You don't have access to `Obj1`, so you need to use a "variable" that you do have access to - in this case, you have `this` which always refers to the current instance of the class.

So although you are still using the same *object* (the one created by `new ObjectA()`), you simply have different variables which refer to that object, depending on which code you are currently looking at. The scoping rules do get a little more complex, but the more you play around with Java, and the more you understand classes vs instances vs references to instances, the easier it becomes to use them comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

The only reference an object has to itself is the `this` keyword. Ultimately, there is no other way for an object to refer to itself.

Comment: You may assign another reference to this.